# What is the process of executing r codes in the form of an executable program in Windows OS?

Tags: r, windows, executable

I have created a string of code in r to do some analysis. I plan to make these codes in the form of an executable program in Windows. What is the process of doing this?
Some of the relevant codes are as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(EnvStats)
library(plotrix)
library(tidyverse)
library(emmeans)
library(multcomp)
library(ggplot2)

fn_G <- function(x){
  replace (replace(x, x > 35 ,  mean (x[x<= 35 ])) ,  x < 5 ,  mean (x[x>= 5 ]))
}

df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(Samples) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("GOI"), fn_G)) 

View(df1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, R does not have the capability of run code in form of an executable.

However, you can use the `RScript.exe`, located in the the "bin" directory within the installation folder of R.

You would save your code as an *.r file and then call `RScript` from a command window like this:

```
Path_to_R_installation\bin\x64\RScript.exe < Path_to_your_RCode\your_code.r
```